# How can I get action name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor, aop

I replaced the ASP.NET ControllerFactory by a  WindsorControllerFactory.

And I registered all controllers and interceptors. Until here everything working well.

Now when I am debuging my Interceptor I always get Execute from **ControllerBase** in **invocation.Method.Name**. I need to get the action name and the parameters of the action to do some validations.

How can I get the action name and the action parameters in the Intercept method of my Interceptor? The information of **ControllerBase_Execute** method and his parameters don't help me.

Thanks,

Raphael Molesim

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get that from the RequestContext.RouteData collection.  I think the keys for the method/action is "action".  Something like:

```
requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Comment: Nice! It works. 

But I'm not really happy with this. I would like intercepting the real action. Now I will need to render a error, in my interceptor method, How can I do that? If I have the real controller I would do something like controller.ModelState.AddModelError() and after I could do some View(model).

Thanks,

Raphael Molesim

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly.  Could you provide some sample code of your interceptor -- how its integrated in ControllerBase.Execute, what it's doing and what you'd like it to do?